# Two-way folder sync with robocopy

Tags: batch-file

So I've been trying to write a batch file which will sync my local Google Drive folder with my flash drive when I run it. Since robocopy is a one-way process, I set up my code so it asks you whether you want to either sync TO Google Drive or FROM Google Drive. This is so that regardless of which of the two locations I make or edit something, I can always sync the newest version onto both locations.

Before anything happens, the code also verifies that it's plugged into my computer and not someone else's by checking its name.

This is what my code looks like right now:

```
@echo off
If "%computername%"=="JAKE-PC" (
color 02
set /P c=Sync TO or FROM Google Drive[T/F]?

:choice
if /I "%c%" EQU "T" goto :to
if /I "%c%" EQU "F" goto :from
goto :choice

:to
echo Syncing to Google Drive...
robocopy ".\Google Drive\ " "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\ " * /mir /xo
goto :done

:from
echo Syncing from Google Drive...
robocopy "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\ " ".\Google Drive\ " * /mir /xo
goto :done

:done
echo Sync Complete.               
pause
)

If NOT "%computername%"=="JAKE-PC" (
color 04
echo Not Jake's PC!
pause
)
```

It seems to work okay. If I make a change on the flash drive, I run the batch file and type T which will sync my changes to Google Drive. If I make a change on Google Drive, I type F which will sync changes from Google Drive.

There's only one flaw however, and that's if each location has new content to sync. If I create "a.txt" on my flash drive and "b.txt" on Google Drive, and then if I:

-sync TO Google Drive, a.txt is copied to Google Drive from my flash drive but b.txt is gone from both.

-sync FROM Google Drive, b.txt is copied to my flash drive from Google Drive but a.txt is gone from both.

So this causes the problem of files being lost forever if there's new content on both locations. Is there any way to fix this? I just need a two-way method of syncing both locations without the possibility of losing files/folders from one of them. Maybe even without robocopy.

Comment: Have you looked into the use of RoboCopy GUI?  It is way too cool!   It will give you a visual way to create your RoboCopy command-line - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx

Answer (score 5):

As per `ROBOCOPY /?` (or [ROBOCOPY.exe doc](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)), `/MIR` option forces implicite `/PURGE`:

```
  /MIR : MIRror a directory tree - equivalent to /PURGE plus all subfolders (/E)
/PURGE : Delete destination files/folders that no longer exist in source.
   /XO : eXclude Older - if destination file exists and is the same date or newer
                         than the source - don’t bother to overwrite it.
    /E : Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders.
```

Use `/E` instead of `/MIR` option and perform copy in both ways unattended:

```
@echo off

If "%computername%"=="JAKE-PC" goto :sync
color 04
echo Not Jake's PC!
goto :done

:sync
color 02

:to
echo Syncing to Google Drive...
robocopy ".\Google Drive\\" "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\\" * /E /XO

:from
echo Syncing from Google Drive...
robocopy "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\\" ".\Google Drive\\" * /E /XO

echo Sync Complete.               

:done
pause
```

Or something similar to next code snippet (keeping `set /P` user's interpelation):

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
If "%computername%"=="JAKE-PC" goto :sync
color 04
echo Not Jake's PC!
goto :done

:to
echo Syncing to Google Drive...
robocopy ".\Google Drive\\" "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\\" * /E /XO
goto :eof

:from
echo Syncing from Google Drive...
robocopy "C:\Users\Jake\Google Drive\\" ".\Google Drive\\" * /E /XO
goto :eof

:sync
color 02
set /P c=Sync TO or FROM Google Drive or BOTH or NOTHING [T/F/B/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "T" ( call :to
  goto :done  
)
if /I "%c%" EQU "F" ( call :from
  goto :done  
)
if /I "%c%" EQU "B" (
  call :to
  call :from
  goto :done  
)
if /I not "%c%" EQU "N" goto :sync
echo No Sync 

:done
echo Sync Complete.               
pause
```

Note that if [Command Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are disabled [`GOTO` will no longer recognise the `:EOF` label](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) (use `exit /B` instead of `goto :EOF` in the case). Although [Command Extensions are enabled by default](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html), we can't presume in it. That's why I use `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions` as a matter of general principle.

> If Command Extensions are enabled `GOTO` changes as follows:
>
> `GOTO` command now accepts a target label of `:EOF` which transfers
>   control to the end of the current batch script file. This is an easy
>   way to exit  a batch script file without defining a label.
>
> Type `CALL /?`  for a description of extensions to the `CALL` command
>   that make this feature useful.

Also note that [Using `GOTO` within parentheses - including `FOR` and `IF` commands - will break their context](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html).

Comment: Very nice! This helps a lot. I have some questions though. What's the difference between using "/e /xo" vs "/mir /xo /xx"? Also with this code, I can't delete a file from one location and have it disappear from the other as well.

Comment: Oh and why was "SETLOCAL EnableExtensions" necessary in the beginning in the second code, out of curiosity? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`/XX` switch to `eXclude eXtra files and directories` should do what you need as per [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/314503/what-does-robocopy-mean-by-tweaked-lonely-and-extra):

> An "extra" file is present in destination but not source; excluding extras will prevent any deletions from the destination.